# Using multiple assemblies in one specflow project

Tags: c#, specflow

I want to use multiple assemblies for one project, I have in two projects steps that I need in my project. I can use only one assembly to get those steps but when I try to use multiple I cannot do it. Can this be done?

```
{
  "stepAssemblies": 
    {
      "assembly": [ "A", "B" ]
    }
  
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Are both assemblies in the build output directory for the project?

Comment: The assembly names must be the exact names of the DLL files, without the `.dll` part of the file name.

Comment: See [Bindings from External Assemblies](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Use-Bindings-from-External-Assemblies.html).

Comment: Yes, they are, but if I run the code like that I am getting error that assembly not good, with one its working,adding second no more

Comment: My problem is how to add more than one to same project. With one it's working fine.

Comment: Hm. Interesting. Are you referencing both Assemblies in your project - that is, did you add both DLL files as references in Visual Studio?

Comment: Did that as well, does my code is written right? assembly and add two ones? did you try this for your own?

Comment: Oh, wait! I think I know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"assemblies"` property must be a string. It cannot be an array. Instead, you need multiple objects each with their or `"assemblies"` property:

```json
{
  "stepAssemblies": [ // <----- array
    { "assembly": "A" }, // <-- object
    { "assembly": "B" }  // <-- object
  ]
}
```

The format of the JSON was incorrect. See [Bindings from External Assemblies](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Bindings/Use-Bindings-from-External-Assemblies.html) for more info about the JSON structure.

Comment: Thank you, that was my problem, json was in the wrong format