# SpecFlow: Imported NuGet package step definitions not recognized in feature files

Tags: c#, nuget, bdd, specflow

I am using SpecFlow for web client tests, and I have created a set of step definitions that I packaged into a NuGet package. I have successfully imported the package into my project, but the step definitions from the package are not recognized in my feature file:

```
Feature: Log In


Scenario: User Log in
    When initialize App Tests
    When login to 'test-app' with creds 'user' 'password'
    Then wait for '10' seconds
    Then logout
```

I followed the steps to import the NuGet package and verified that it is correctly installed and listed in the project dependencies. However, when I try to use the step definitions in my feature files, they are not recognized and I get the following message when running the test:

> No matching step definition found for one or more steps.

```
using System;
using TechTalk.SpecFlow;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    [Binding]
    public class StepDefinitions
    {
        private readonly ScenarioContext _scenarioContext;

        public StepDefinitions(ScenarioContext scenarioContext)
        {
            _scenarioContext = scenarioContext;
        }
        [When(@"login to '(.*)' with creds '(.*)' '(.*)'")]
        public void WhenLoginToWithCreds(string p0, string p1, string p2)
        {
            _scenarioContext.Pending();
        }

...
```

I have checked the following:

The [Binding] attribute is applied to the step definition class in the NuGet package.
The step definition methods have the correct attributes ([Given], [When], or [Then]) and matching regex or attribute arguments.
I have also made sure to build my project after any changes and verified that the feature files import the correct namespace.

Despite these checks, the step definitions from the NuGet package are still not recognized in my feature files. What could be causing this issue? Am I missing any additional steps?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using multiple assemblies in one specflow project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69297750/3092298)

Comment: I originally voted to close this as a duplicate of the wrong question. Essentially you need to use step bindings from external assemblies, you just need to specify the DLL files in those NuGet packages in specflow.json. The answer I linked to above shows you how, you just need the assembly names (DLL file names).

Comment: @GregBurghardt that helped me solve it, the main issue was that I didn't have a specflow.json file, so after adding this with the assembly reference was good to go

Comment: You can actually mark this question as a duplicate of that other one. Being a duplicate is not a bad thing. It gives people multiple things to search the internet for, which funnels people to the same canonical answer. I bet you aren't the only person who has tried using a NuGet package for step bindings, so they search for "nuget" but not "external assemblies".